# A peculiar problem in my writing skills

Tags: resources

I have a problem and I'm not sure how common it is. I have often heard people say that reading will, just by pure habit, always develop the writing skills of a reader; that just by sheer recognition of style and function of how sentences are formed, one can learn good writing technique even if he/she can't fully grasp the rules involved.

For me, that has not really been the case. What I often notice about myself is that *I know* something feels off when I make a mistake writing, and yet I'm not able to actually tell where my grammatical error is. I love literature and love being able to express my thoughts in writing, but I think that because I'm an ESL student (came to USA when I was 7, I am now 27), there is a fundamental gap in my understanding of grammar that has never been filled.

In light of this problem, are there any resources I can use to go back and relearn grammatical structure? I would appreciate any recommendation.

Comment: Hi sten33, welcome to StackExchange! Judging from your question, it honestly doesn't seem to me like you have a grammar problem. You form sentences very well and I had no trouble reading or understanding your question. That being said, if you are worried about your foundational grammar skills, taking a college-level creative writing or English class to refresh yourself on English grammar and prose techniques is a great start. You may also want to look at Pro Writing Aid, Writing Forward and Daily Grammar.

Comment: Also maybe take a look at the [English Language Learners StackExchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) and the [English Language and Usage StackExchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/) for specific points questions. *Shameless plugging, yay*

Comment: Hi sten33, I have a couple of questions. 1) You said that you are an ESL student - would you say that you are fully fluent in English by now? 2) How much actual writing (including school essays) have you actually done?

Comment: https://www.edx.org/search?q=english+grammar

Comment: - https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/ 
- https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=7966969587636132610

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not peculiar. In my long career as a book editor, I have encountered many writers who have an intuitive grasp of writing but cannot analyze a problem or articulate the grammatical issues involved. I developed this skill in myself by reading many books on grammar and usage (popular books, not textbooks). A book favored by many writers and editors today is *Garner's Modern English Usage* by Bryan Garner.